# WPF show data in another window from datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop

I have a datagrid in mainwindow and there is a detail button in datagrid . I wanna click detail button show data(row) in another window. Only Textblocks.

[image]

Grid XAML

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" RowHeaderWidth="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Verdana" CanUserResizeRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" ClipboardCopyMode="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" AutomationProperties.IsColumnHeader="True" AutomationProperties.IsOffscreenBehavior="Onscreen" CellStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridCellStyle1}" CanUserResizeColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FF0194CA" Foreground="Black" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="{x:Null}" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Başlık" Width="500" CanUserResize="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=baslik}"  FontSize="13" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="10" Background="{x:Null}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Büyüklük" Width="100" CanUserResize="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=metrekare}" FontSize="13" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="10"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Konum" Width="196" CanUserResize="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=mevkii}" FontSize="13" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="10"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Detay" CanUserResize="False" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Ilan Detayları" Click="DetayButton_Click" FontSize="13" FontFamily="Verdana" Padding="10" Margin="0,10,26,10" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

MainWindow Datagrid Process

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection yeni = new SQLiteConnection(baglanti);
        yeni.Open();

        string sorgu = "Select * From Gayrimenkul";

        // SQLiteCommand komutislet = new SQLiteCommand(sorgu,baglanti);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sorgu, baglanti);
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        yeni.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `object sender` to determin the button you clicked (and the ID of the object you're trying to recieve) and then parameterize your query so its something like `SELECT * FROM YourTableHere where ID = @someattribute`.

If you post more information i can help you further.

Comment: I don't know how will do . I can send all files. Mail or another way ?

Comment: You select them out of the database with your SQL SELECT statement. Did you correctly implement a database?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution,I am sharing for friends ;
This is detail window.

```
    public partial class DetayWindow : Window
{
    public DetayWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string baslik { get; set; }
    public string yazi { get; set; }
    public string tarih { get; set; }
    public string mevkii { get; set; }
    public string metrekare { get; set; }
    public string tur { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //textbox1.Text = sifre;
        //text1.Text = kullaniciAdi;

        idtext.Text = id;
        turtext.Text = tur;
        metrekaretext.Text = metrekare;
        konumtext.Text = mevkii;
        tarihtext.Text = tarih;
        yazitext.Text = yazi;
        basliktext.Text = baslik;

    }
}
```

This is MainWindow Click Button ;

```
        private void DetayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DetayWindow pencere = new DetayWindow();
        string sorgu = "Select * From Gayrimenkul";
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sorgu, baglanti);
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        int i = dataGrid1.SelectedIndex;

        string veribaslik = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["baslik"].ToString();
        string veriyazi = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["yazi"].ToString();
        string veritarih = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["tarih"].ToString();
        string verimevkii = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["mevkii"].ToString();
        string verimetrekare = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["metrekare"].ToString();
        string veritur = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["tur"].ToString();
        string veriid = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"].ToString();

        pencere.baslik = veribaslik;
        pencere.yazi = veriyazi;
        pencere.tarih = veritarih;
        pencere.mevkii = verimevkii;
        pencere.metrekare = verimetrekare;
        pencere.tur = veritur;
        pencere.id = veriid;

        pencere.ShowDialog();
    }
```